# removing inner table filter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a filterable table containing a collapsible list in a column. The collapsible contains another table. [Sample of the situation.](http://www.bootply.com/0qNa2CAD24#)

The problem is that when anything is written to filter only the required items, the inner table also gets filtered.  Is there a way to avoid this.

Suggestions about how else to display something like this are also welcome.

Comment: I think it's because you put `$('.searchable tr').hide();`, it will remove the inner table. Can you explain how you want to filter the inner table ? By Name or what ?

Comment: filtering the outer table is good enough for me. When I write "some collapsible2" only that row with that collapsible should be shown. The inner table should be intact. I'm curious about how to filter depending on a column as well but thats another thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter only from the Name column, you can try to use below [code](http://www.bootply.com/p62WL2BXPu):

```
    $('#filter').keyup(function () {
        var stringValue = $(this).val();
        $("#outer-table tr.row").each( function( index ) {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).find(".panel-title a:contains("+stringValue+")").parents("tr").show();
        });
    });
```

***EDIT: I have tested the new code above, it works as expected.***

HTML changes, easier to get **ONLY** every `<tr>` that are part of your outer-table:

1. Change your outer-table tag from `<tbody class="searchable">`, into this, `<tbody id="outer-table" class="searchable">`
2. Then add a selector to every `<tr>` inside outer-table but **NOT** inside inner-table, like this:

   ```
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
           <td><div id="collapsibleMain2" class="panel-group">

    </tr>
    <!-- and so on -->
   ```

For more info about the jQuery functions that I used above:

- [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)
- [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)
- [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)